# How to resolve 'Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.'

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

I need to `throw RuntimeException` when length of two lists is not equal. We are using `SonarQube` tool for code review purpose.

**Here is the code:**

```
if (objctArray.length != columnArray.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("objctArray and columnArray length is not same. objctArray length = %d, columnArray length = %d", objctArray.length, columnArray.length));
            }
```

Now, `SonarQube` raises issue that `Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.` at `throw new RuntimeException` line. I don't know which exception I can replace to resolve `SonarQube` issue.

Comment: The message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If those two lists are arguments passed to a method, `IllegalArgumentException` would be a good candidate to throw. It's a sub-class of `RuntimeException`, so you'll still be throwing a kind of `RuntimeException`.

```
if (objctArray.length != columnArray.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("objctArray and columnArray length is not same. objctArray length = %d, columnArray length = %d", objctArray.length, columnArray.length));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Don't throw generic exceptions](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontThrowGenericExceptions). You should be subclassing Exception and then throwing your subclass, so that the type of the exception actually provides information about what is going on, allowing clients of the function to catch and treat it appropriately.